# How to retain Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image content color irrespective of layout background color?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp, windows-community-toolkit

Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image content color changed when background-color changes in Layout. How to retain Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Image content color?

**Issue Facing**

Image color combined with the layout background-color as below screenshots

Background Color - Black
[image: Background Color - Black]

Background Color - White
[image: Background Color - White]

Background Color - Green
[image: Background Color - Green]

The content color is dynamically changing with respect to the layout background-color

**Expected Solution**

The content color should be the same irrespective of the layout background-color

Sample link :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KXp3yCYSBmgbKsXVNjB6T0LPsl6Pply8/view?usp=sharing

**Replication procedure**

1. Run the sample
2. Click Button(Name: Color)(When background changes. Image content
   color will also change)

Comment: I don't quite understand what your problem is?

Comment: I have modified the question with more clarity. Kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

[WriteableBitmap Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%253Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=winrt-19041) provides a BitmapSource that can be written to and updated, and the whole picture is one, which causes the color of the image to be affected by the Canvas background. When the background of Canvas becomes green, red and green are superimposed, so the red pattern becomes yellow.

To do this, when you change the background of Canvas, you could traverse the pixels of the entire picture, and if you find a pixel block that is not red, then change it. Please refer to the second reply of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108974/how-to-improve-performance-of-changing-image-pixel-colour-using-writeablebitmape/37318274#37318274).